# Writing a standard string + name of a list + content of a list in Python

Tags: list, loops, printing

I have 10 different lists, like:

```
greetings = ["hello", "hi"]

wishes = ["happy bday", "merry Xmas"]

pets = ["dog", "cat"]
```

I want to have, as output, a standard string with the name of the list + the content of the list (also between brackets). Something like:

```
"Content of greetings:  hello, hi"
"Content of wishes: happy bday, merry Xmas"
"Content of pets: dog, cat"
```

Is there a way to do it without writing every time the same block of code? Like:

```
print ("Content of = %s" %(greetings))
print ("Content of = %s" %(wishes))
print ("Content of = %s" %(pets))
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use dictionary. Then keys are strings "greetings", "wishes", etc. and the values are lists. Then you just iterate over items of this dictionary and print them.